# Extend click() method of Webdriver or Selenium2 to calculate web page response

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am planning to calculate page response time using following code, but this is causing redundancy.

```
  long start;
  start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
  driver.get(url); or click();
  System.out.println (driver.getTitle() + " - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " MilliSec");
```

I am aware of implementing above code using Page objects, need help in extending the click() using Webdriver interface, so that when I call click() above code is automatically executed.

Comment: any accepted solutions to this?

Answer (score 2):

As I did read your comment, there is also one more possibility. Build your own class which will implement the WebElement interface. In that case you will have to implement **all** the methods of WebElement, which is probably not worth it. But if you would like to go by that approach I would suggest something like this:

```
public class MyWebElement implements WebElement{
  private WebElement element

  //... all the WebElement methods must be implemented
  //but I will show only the click:

  @Override
     public void click(){
     long start;
     start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
     element.click();
     System.out.println (driver.getTitle() + " - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " MilliSec");

  }
}
```

And later in the code:

```
@Test
public void testSomething(){
  driver.get("http://foo.bar");
  MyWebElement elem = driver.find(By.id("baz"));
  elem.click();
}
```

Again: By using this approach you **must** implement *all* WebElement methods - even those you will never ever use in your tests. Being in your position, I would use the approach as I hinted in mz previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I implement it is that I write my own Java Class which should represent the page. So If I want to test Google, I have some class which looks like this:

```
public class GoogleUI{
   private WebElement searchButton;
   private WebDriver driver;

   public GoogleUI(){
     driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   }

  public void clickSearch(){
   long start;
   searchButton = driver.findElement(By.name("btnG"));
   start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
   searchButton.click();
   System.out.println (driver.getTitle() + " - " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " MilliSec"); 

  }
}
```

And later in the test:

```
@Test
public void testGoogleSearchButton(){
   GoogleUI google = new GoogleUI();
   google.clickSearch();
}
```

Where the `clickSearch` method itself wraps the click and prints the time.

This is obviously stripped down to absolute minimum, but I hope you can adapt it in your testing

Comment: I am using similar technique using page objects. Require help in extending the Click() method using Webdriver interface.